# Problem with Add to Cart form in views containing the Add to cart form

Tags: commerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commerce - Views - Taxonomy - add to cart issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/commerce-views-taxonomy-add-to-cart-issue)

I am creating a product discount based on a discount field present in product display following some real assistance from guys at IRC and Bojan Zivanovic. Refer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/discount-based-on-a-field-in-product-display-node-in-drupal-commerce)

The add to cart form on the product node display works fine as expected but if I use add to cart form present in Views, products are added to the cart but no discounts are applied because discounts are based on initial display_path present on the node display pages. I tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/commerce-views-taxonomy-add-to-cart-issue) but couldn't figure out comment from rszrama.

My question is how will I make views know about the node context i.e display_path?